# Woocommerce: Extend admin product list quick filters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter, plugins, product

I need to extend the quick filters provided by Woocommerce in the admin product view but I cannot seem to find the proper hook to achieve this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is the view that I want to extend with two links that directly filter the product list by a certain category (which is regularly buried deep in the category dropdown so the customer wants it above to have a one click solution):

[image]

I've already set up a custom plugin and tried to find the proper hook but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can add these categories - https://prnt.sc/gFuhHx_BKupB

```
function add_custom_category_links( $views ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $taxonomy       = 'product_cat';
    $current_term   = isset( $_GET[ $taxonomy ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ $taxonomy ] ) : '';
    $current_status = isset( $_GET['post_status'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['post_status'] ) : '';

    //Change to categories you want to add
    $category_links = array(
        'clothes' => 'Clothes',
        'shoes'   => 'Shoes',
    );

    $output = array();
    foreach ( $views as $key => $view ) {
        $output[ $key ] = $view;
        if ( $key === 'publish' ) {
            foreach ( $category_links as $slug => $name ) {
                $class = ( $slug === $current_term ) ? 'current' : '';

                $url = add_query_arg(
                    array(
                        $taxonomy     => $slug,
                        'post_status' => $current_status,
                        'post_type'   => 'product',
                        'paged'       => 1,
                    ),
                    admin_url( 'edit.php' )
                );

                $output[ 'category-' . $slug ] = "<a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a>";
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'views_edit-product', 'add_custom_category_links' );
```